# How to set event handler for a GPIO in Mathematica for Raspbian

Tags: rpi.gpio, wolfram-engine

I wish to program my Raspberry Pi using *Mathematica* (rather than *Python*). One basic functionality easily done with *Python* is to set `event handlers` which triggers a function when some event is perceived on a GPIO pin.

How can I set up and event handler in *Mathematica*?

For example, here is some basic Python code that spies at pin 17:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

def fct_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(17):
        print("Pin 17 just went ON")
    else:
        print("Pin 17 just went OFF")

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.add_event_detect(17, GPIO.BOTH, callback=fct_callback)

message = input("Press enter to finish the program\n\n")
GPIO.cleanup()
```

What would be the equivalent of this code in *Mathematica*?

Comment: whatvresearch have you done? ... a quick internet search reveals some example Mathematica code that interfaces to GPIO

Comment: @jsotola: there are a few pages indicating how to read an input or write in output mode. I want an event handler, and that, I found no examples.

Comment: This page [https://reference.wolfram.com/language/workflow/AccessGPIOOnRaspberryPi.html ]describes ``DeviceRead`` and ``DeviceWrite``. However, unless I run an endless loop, there is no function that will be triggered on status change.

Comment: @jstola: The EventHandler command from Mathematica handles events from the mouse, the keyboard, or when a Mathematica menu is chosen. I cannot see how events from GPIO could be plugged into this command.